# Signal Processing/FFT On Live Input Audio

Tags: windows, signal-processing, real-time, fft

I was told this belongs in programming, not in the Signal Processing sub-exchange.

Is there a way to implement spectrum analysis (specifically FFT) on live audio in Windows?

I want to be able to read in audio from a microphone, and have a display on the screen that shows the resultant Fourier Transform.

It would also be useful if I could execute a program if a certain set of FFT characteristics occurred.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Any particular programming language ?

Comment: @PaulR Java, C, C++, and Matlab are all feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you have a couple of options depending on your most preferred language/framework basically. I'm not sure how new you are to signal processing so I'll suggest a few options.

### Visual Programming

These are all visual programming environments which don't actually require any writing of code, however Simulink and Pure Data both require a runtime for the user to run the program.

#### [Simulink](https://de.mathworks.com/products/simulink.html) (Paid)

MathWorks/Matlab's visual programming tool that works really well in real-time (in my opinion). Using the [Audio System Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/products/audio-system.html), you can easily capture microphone input from your system in realtime and carry out the [FFT](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fft.html) processing, plot the spectrum and, like you said, if certain FFT conditions are met then to carry out some further processing.

This isn't free software and requires having the Matlab/Simulink run-time installed to be used. You can also script your processing in Matlab's .m language as desired (a cross between Java, JS and C).

#### [Max MSP](https://cycling74.com/products/max/) (Paid)

A similar version to Simulink but developed as a standalone visual programming tool. This will allow you similar freedom to Simulink but I think it will be easier for re-distribution.

You can [compile](https://cycling74.com/forums/how-do-you-build-a-standalone-max-msp-application) MAX MSP into executables to give to someone straight away. Here is a reference to get you started on [using the FFT](https://docs.cycling74.com/max5/tutorials/msp-tut/mspchapter25.html) in MAX. Again, this isn't free but if you wanted to learn more about it then I think it's worth the money (if I recall it's not too expensive).

If you need some more custom processing than the built in modules, I believe you can design custom MAX modules using C or JavaScript. Max is designed to easily get system audio input / outputs and [here's a link](https://docs.cycling74.com/max7/tutorials/04_mspaudioio) to get you started.

Bonus: You can design your own Ableton Live plugins with the [Max4Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/max-for-live/) addon which just lets your MAX MSP projects get compiled into [.VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) format. So you can build custom FX if you are into music production.

#### [Pure Data (PD)](https://puredata.info/) (Free)

A very bland open source version of MAX MSP but completely free. It may look dull at first but a lot of researches I know use it to build fairly complex systems that can do some serious data processing. There are also lots of community built extras for PD if you ever needed a custom module. Here is a link to get you started on the [FFT](http://pd-tutorial.com/english/ch03s08.html) in PD. You cannot compile applications with PD, but since it's completely free to install anyone can run your program after installing PD. Another [link](https://puredata.info/docs/faq/audioinput) for troubleshooting audio I/O in PD (if it isn't working right out of the box).

## Programming Languages

Now the visual stuff is a really good way to get started if you aren't already introduced to DSP or audio programming. Otherwise here a just a few options and links to get started and where I would recommend.

#### [Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) & [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

Like before, the [Audio Systems Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/products/audio-system.html) supports realtime audio I/O within a Matlab script. This combined with Matlab's built in [FFT](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) function can have you setup programming realtime FFTs and plotting the response in no time at all (less than 10 lines of code or something).

[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) has it's own version of the FFT function and different backends for rendering plot responses, but no Audio Systems Toolbox. However, [Playrec](http://www.playrec.co.uk/) is also an opensource alternative for audio I/O in Matlab/Octave that supports realtime audio input and output.

([Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is an open source equivalent to Matlab (Matlab needs a paid license to develop a program), but does not support all Matlab supported features).

#### [Python](https://www.python.org/)

Due to the [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) module, realtime audio I/O and DSP is more possible using Python! I would recommend Python if you are just starting out for sure since it's a nice introduction into any programming language and can help with teaching the fundamentals of DSP before attempting lower level languages.

[Here's](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o) where you can get started with real-time non-blocking audio I/O in Python with PyAudio. To plot your data you can use a library such as [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) (designed similar to Matlab's easy plotting functionality).

For your FFT there are multiple libraries out there but I'd start with the [Scipy / Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) one.

#### C

One of the classic (and sometimes) most daunting programming language. With no objects (unless you want to make them yourself) or other high level abstractions, C is one of the few languages that still feels like you're building a lot from the ground up (which personally I like).

To get started with audio, I'd look at, in my opinion, the most widely used cross-platform audio I/O library; [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/). This will let you access the soundcard data inputs and outputs in realtime on Mac, Linux & Windows.

Once you get this up and running an FFT I would use to get started would be the [KissFFT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) just because of it's pure simplicity to use. If you want to plot the data, I would maybe look at [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), but this is'nt a very pretty route in terms of development.

If you are very new to programming I would not recommend this unless you really want to get stuck in.

#### C++

Both [KissFFT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) and [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) will also compile with C++ code, but here are a couple of higher level alternatives.

One of my favourites is the [JUCE](https://juce.com/) framework / development environment. It has built in cross-platform audio I/O and already has a custom [FFT](https://docs.juce.com/master/classdsp_1_1FFT.html) function as part of the framework. You can build custom [VSTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) for your music [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) if you want to as well. It also comes with 'easy' (if you know C++) access to graphics windows with higher level access to openGL, so you could get fancy when plotting your data in real-time. If i remember correctly, one of the Demo projects on first installation is a real-time FFT plot you can compile and see the input from your laptop mic. JUCE is free for personal use, but comes with a small license fee as an indie developer.

Otherwise another one that comes to mind is the [QT](https://www.qt.io/) C++ library/framework for UI design (mainly). This is a cross platform easy to use GUI designer, that also has high level classes for obtaining audio input from a Mac/Win/Linux mic. [Here](https://github.com/michaelfranzl/qt-fft-realtime-spectrum) is just one example I came across using [QT's multimedia classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-module.html) and [FFTReal](http://ldesoras.free.fr/prod.html) to plot a realtime FFT spectrum.

## Summary

I've suggested a lot of options, but also missed out a few other people may recommend like languages such as [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), [Java](https://java.com/de/download/), [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) etc... and there are so many suggestions it's impossible to cover them all but I think this should be enough to get started. If it were me in terms of experience:

- Complete Beginner to Programming: [Max MSP](https://cycling74.com/forums/how-do-you-build-a-standalone-max-msp-application)
- Novice / Knows their way around a little bit: [Python](https://www.python.org/) (with [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/))
- Programmed in other languages maybe looking to gain more programming skills : C++ with [JUCE](https://juce.com/)

Any of these languages you pick will be good in future reference for software positions and many companies / researchers use them to prototype / develop realtime audio processing software.

This is just my opinion but hopefully this gets you well along your way!

Comment: Thank you so much Woody!  This is incredibly helpful!

Comment: Really good answer! Although I would recommend sounddevice instead of pyaudio. Also if you start with python & numpy you can easily port it to C++ & xtensor-fftw (regardless of the audio library used).